# How do I manually set tnid when migrating nodes?

Tags: nodes, migrations, i18n-l10n

I need to manually set tnid during migration.

My code:

```
  public function complete($entity, $row) {

    // load the newly created node (just in case entity isn't fully populated).
    $node = node_load($entity->nid);
    $node->tnid = '66';
    $node->title = 'CHANGE THIS !';

    // create the field collection item entity
    $item = entity_create('field_collection_item', $values);

    // attach it to the node loaded above
    $item->setHostEntity('node', $node);

    // save the entity
    $item->save();
  }
```

The node 66 exists and is active, but when I check on translations, the new node isn't associated. Instead the  title is changed with "changed this", then the new node is updated.

With Devel I see that the node has tnid 66.

Comment: Hi, monkeyUser. What do you  mean "check on translations"?

Answer (score 0):

You want to give the node a language, and set the source node in the `translation_source` key:

```
$node->language = 'es';
$node->translation_source = node_load(66);
```

Reference: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!translation!translation.module/function/translation_node_prepare/7